# nginx multiple default blocks on different ports with redirects

Tags: nginx

I currently have two nginx server blocks to process the requests to any subdomain under `example.com`. Add subdomains under `example.com` must be server only with HTTPS. And so the server blocks are as such:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$;
    root /var/www/x;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

**Objective**

Now, I also want to add a default server block for **ANY** other server names, but all of its traffic should only be served on HTTP, not HTTPS.

So the first trial was:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/app;
    ...
}
```

Which works great, but if the processed request was as such: `https://abc.def.com` then the user will get the "Your connection is not private" scary error, where in fact I'd love if they'd get redirected to HTTP.

If I add:

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Then this works, but the second server block stops working and I get that the server is unable to handle the request.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where are you going to get a TLS certificate for every possible domain that you don't host?

Comment: Hah not for _every_ possible domain, just with my customers! SAN certificates ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either listen on port `443` or you don't. If you listen on it, you'll get answer on every hostname pointed to that IP, as the information on hostname is only transferred within the established connection. If you manually type `https://` on a non-HTTPS site and the same IP listens on both port `80` for HTTP and `443` for HTTPS, you'll get the warning on all hostnames without a proper TLS certificate.

You have two options:

1. Make every site available on HTTPS. This shouldn't be a problem in this era of [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) and [*Server Name Indication*](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni) (SNI). This is the only rational solution this day.
2. Have a separate IP address (e.g. `198.51.100.2`) for sites without HTTPS, point them to it. Listen to HTTPS on e.g. `198.51.100.1`, and the `198.51.100.2:443` simply doesn't answer:

   ```
   server {
       listen *:80 default_server;
       ...
   }

   server {
       listen 198.51.100.1:443 default_server ssl;
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: That would be using SANs to get for all domains, right? I like the IP solution, but it's going to be a bit hard to manage as I scale.

Comment: SAN, if you prefer one certificate. With Let's Encrypt you can have up to 100 SAN domains. Another approach is SNI, allowing multiple certificates on a single IP.